# Error when inflating my layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developping both on 7 inch screen and on an htc m8. I have many layout xml files that are running fine. I have one fragment that is creating the problem. I run it on my samsung 7 inch screen in landscape mode setup in manifest.

My tablet is running like a charm. Then I copy my large-land file in layout-land and try to run my code on the htc. I've done this method many times.

But here I get a crash when running inflater.inflate.

something must be wrong in the xml? the stack trace and my layout xml file is joined.
I'm stuck. any ideas?
I don't see any clues in the trace that points me to the issue.

I add the stack as jpg because something is not liked about my format by stackoverflow.

[image]

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/LightSkyBlue"
    tools:context="com.example.bernard.speechparole.Cards">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/title_cards_ex"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_cards_ex"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/help"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/work_validation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/pro_validation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_cards_ex"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/work_validation"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/work_validation"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/help"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/next"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/next"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/work_answer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/work_validation"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/work_validation"
        android:ems="7"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/resp_card"
        android:textSize="29dp"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/resp_card"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/work_validation"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mem_report"
        android:id="@+id/report_card"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_below="@id/work_answer"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/work_validation"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure that drawable you're referencing is in the drawable folder. Depending on what device you're using it may not locate it.

Comment: it can be android version issue. please post crash logs here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with one of your string or drawable resource. Check the id of the resource in the exception and search for it in `R.java` to figure out which resource is causing the problem or just see if something is highlighted in red in your XML.

Comment: there is no red in the xml. Could you share a bit more details on how to do: Check the id of the resource in the exception and search for it in R.java to figure out which resource is causing the problem

Comment: Check the id after "failure getting entry for..." In your screenshot or better latest logcat. Find and open your project's R.java (auto-generated). See the name of resource against the rowing resource id that is shown in your logs.